# Retrieving data from Firebase as a tuple in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve 3 pieces of information 1. Blood Pressure Entry Date, 2. Diastolic Blood Pressure, 3. Systolic Blood Pressure from each Date under the Blood Pressure Tacking node. The date and Blood Pressure Entry Date are the same. I used the date as a node to organize and write over existing data if the user enters another entry for that particular date. I am trying to get the the information as a tuple so it can be used to build a chart. Since the dates vary I am not sure how to call them to get to the data I need. You can see a screen shot of my firebase database at the link.[Firebase Data Storage Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjA1f.png)

Comment: A couple of things: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and most importantly [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are no tuples in Firebase. You can observe a node which will return a snapshot and then derive data from that. I would suggest writing some code to read the existing structure and perhaps printing to console. Then when you get stuck, post your code and Firebase structure as TEXT please, no images/links, and we'll see if we can help!

Comment: Jay, thanks for the reply and information. I'll work on it and report back with a more detailed explanation of what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)